# Magento 2 Rest API Can't Remove Category ID's from product

Tags: api, rest, magento, magento2

I am working on a REST API call which will remove the category ID from a live product. The below code returns true but this has not updated in the back end or on the site.

I have followed the magento documentation for the update request and that works well, I tried doing the inverse of that with the delete request and following some examples online.

The below method is DELETE.

If someone can advise how this category can be removed then please advise.

```
{
"product": {
"sku": "MRO2222",
"status": "0",
  "category_links": [
    {
      "position": 100,
      "category_id": "8"
    }
  ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a proper way through a delete request with Magento Rest API.

The way to go is to unset the categories of the product and update with the desired categories afterwards.

You can unset the categories with a PUT request to endpoint:
`https://www.yoursite.com/rest/all/V1/products/your_product_sku` (replace url and sku)

with payload:

```
{  
   "product":{  
      "extensionAttributes":{  
         "category_links":[  
            
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant thank you for that. That works perfectly. Another question on this, I am only wanting to remove one category from a list of categories that are stored against a product. Is there anyway of removing just that one category and keeping the rest? so just unset one category rather than them all

Comment: At the moment this can't be done in one proper call unfortunately, but should be fixed in future Magento release. See for example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/20481.

Comment: Do you know if posting an empty `category_links` array still clears all categories for a product in version 2.4?

Comment: Hi Daniel. Yes, that should work.